# Issue adding bootstrap-select plugin in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a select which is populated using ajax call . and i need to call refresh method on that control soon after angular2 has done its job. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: it it better to understand if you put your code along with question. and yes simple select option has no link with angular2

Comment: Check out Dropdown of PrimeNG. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use to angularjs interval to update the component after a certain time.

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Thanks Julian . But i am using angular 2